# Setting variable equal to column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to set the `Player_Season` column equal to the `Year` column of my table. I know how to do this without variables, but I'm not well acquainted with variables in MySQL and would like to know how to do this for educational purposes.  It is affecting the rows when I simply enter a number in place of `Year`. When I enter a column name though, the error reads `Unknown column 'Player_Season' in 'field list`

```
SET @var_name = `Year`;
UPDATE retrosheet.batting_table SET Player_Season = @var_name WHERE id IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I don't think this makes sense, but just in case, could you provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Even with prepared statements, you can't really do this, since the column name can't be a placeholder.

Comment: Okay I guess that answers my question Tim. Thanks

Comment: This is something you can do in SQL server...right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is something you can do in SQL server...right?

No, you can't use a variable or a prepared statement parameter as a column name in any brand of SQL database.

You can *interpolate* the column name into a string and prepare a statement from that. Here's an example that works in MySQL:

```
SET @var_name = 'Year';
SET @myquery = CONCAT('UPDATE retrosheet.batting_table SET Player_Season = ',
  @var_name, ' WHERE id IS NOT NULL';

PREPARE stmt FROM @myquery;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The important part is that **all tables and columns must be fixed at the time of prepare.**

You can use variables and parameters only where you would put constant values in the query, like quoted string literals, quoted date literals, or numeric literals.